# ng-csv doesn't export the new updated data

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-csv to export some json data. The problem is when I make any change inside that object (not to assign a full new object) and try to export again, it exports a csv file with the same old data without any change. here is my code in plunker [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/snzzgwtBVL4iyKtnaeom?p=preview)

```
$scope.getArray = [{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];

$scope.update = function(){
    $scope.getArray[0].a = 100;
    console.log($scope.getArray);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-csv` directive is currently coded to create the csv "string" whenever the *referenced object* that is provided via `ng-csv=` changes.  In order to get the library to realize that it needs to re-do the csv structure,  you need to change the reference to a new object.  The most straightforward way to do this is to do a deep copy of the array, like below:

```
$scope.getArray = [{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];

$scope.update = function(){
  var updated = angular.copy($scope.getArray);
  updated[0].a = 100;
  $scope.getArray = updated;
  console.log($scope.getArray);
}
```

Comment: To be more specific: The thing is ng-csv uses `scope.$watch('prop', fn)`. Instead of that `scope.$watchCollection` or `scope.$watch('prop', fn, *true*)` should be used.